# is there any way to read rtf file using java other than RTFEditorKit?

Tags: java, swing, file-io, rtf, text-extraction

I am trying to read RTF file using Java and I have found Swing's RTFEditorkit.is there any other jar files available to read rtf files. Am not satisfied with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825807/rtf-to-plain-text-in-java).

Comment: do want to extract only plain text ?

Comment: @Sage i want to extract images ,text with their co-ordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kind of information do you want to extract? RTF is a *really* simple format, you should be able to get most information without using a real parser but regular expressions.

Comment: :i want to extract images ,text with their co-ordinates.

Comment: Look inside the file with notepad and search for the images of interest :)

Comment: :ya its working fine ,but am getting huge amount of data when am opening with text editor.so how can i identify the co-ordinates of text and images from there.( am working in linux(ubuntu)).

Comment: Search vor `\picwgoal<number>` `\pichgoal<number>` for example `\picwgoal1035\pichgoal1035` for image dimensions. Getting the position of text is quite hard since it depends on page format. The position can be found in `\posy<number>` / `\posx<number>`

Answer (score 1):

You can try [the kit](http://java-sl.com/advanced_rtf_editor_kit.html) as alternative for default one. It supports images and text as well.