# Display Rich Text in android textview

Tags: android

### For example this is my rich text

{\rtf1\fbidis\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fswiss\fprq2\fcharset0 Candara;}{\f1\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}{\f2\fnil\fcharset0 Candara;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\ltrpar\lang1033\f0\fs24 The coefficient of \f1{\pict\wmetafile8\picw397\pich450\picwgoal225\pichgoal255 
0100090000037000000000004700000000000400000003010800050000000b0200000000050000
000c0212001000030000001e000400000007010400040000000701040047000000410b2000cc00
11000f000000000011000f0000000000280000000f000000110000000100010000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ffffff00fffe0101fffe0101fffe010111fe
0100bbfe0101d7fe0101effe0101d7fe0111bb02010111b60101ffb60101ff960100ff260001ff
fe0001fffe0101fffe0100fffe0101040000002701ffff030000000000
}\f0  in the expansion of \f1{\pict\wmetafile8\picw3466\pich556\picwgoal1965\pichgoal315 
010009000003200100000000f700000000000400000003010800050000000b0200000000050000
000c0216008400030000001e0004000000070104000400000007010400f7000000410b2000cc00
150083000000000015008300000000002800000083000000150000000100010000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ffffff00ffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
ffffe0010101f3fffffffffffffffffffffffff9ffffe0010101efffffffffffffffffffffffff
feffffe0010101dfffffffffffffffffffffffffff7fffe0010101dfffffffffffffffffffffff
ffff7fffe0010101bf83ff7fc47fdff11fffefffffffbfffe0010101bfefff7feeffdffbbfffef
ffffffbfffe0000101bfefff7ff5ffdffd7fffefffffffbfffe0010101bfefff7ffbffdffeffff
efffffffbfffe0010101bfeff007f5fc01fd7ffe00fce73fbfffe0010101bfefff7feeffdffbb8
7feffce73fbfffe0010101bfefff7fc47fdff11b7fefffffffbfffe0010101dfafff7fffffdfff
fdffefffffff7fffe0010101dfcfff7fffffdffffeffefffffff7fffe0010101efefffffffffff
ffff7ffffffffefff800010101f3fffffffffffffffb7ffffffff9fffda0010101ffffffffffff
fffffc7ffffffffffffda0010101fffffffffffffffffffffffffffff81ca0010101ffffffffff
fffffffffffffffffffff920010101ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffe0010001ffffffff
ffffffffffffffffffffffffe0010101040000002701ffff030000000000
}\f0  is\f2\fs23\par
}

---

I want to display rich text in textview

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RTF to Plain Text in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825807/rtf-to-plain-text-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

try this way

```
RTFEditorKit rtfParser = new RTFEditorKit();
Document document = rtfParser.createDefaultDocument();
rtfParser.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(rtfBytes), document, 0);
String text = document.getText(0, document.getLength());
```

credit to [him](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5826234/6478047)

Comment: Why not flag the question as a duplicate rather than copy/pasting someone else's answer?

Comment: i was not sure if the same way would work for android so could flag it.