# How do I extract inline files in RTF format into a list of files?

Tags: java, rtf

I am getting data from an SQL Server database and the content of the column is stored in RTF format. I am using [RTF Parser Kit](https://github.com/joniles/rtfparserkit) and I have managed to convert the rtf to text.

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes());
StringTextConverter converter = new StringTextConverter();
converter.convert(new RtfStreamSource(is));
input = converter.getText();
```

However, some inputs contain inline images. Is there a way to extract all these images in an `ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<>();` using the `RTF Parser Kit` ?

For example, the following :

[image]

is stored like:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1253\uc1\deff1\adeff1\deflang0\deflangfe0\adeflang0{\fonttbl
{\f0\fswiss\fcharset0\fprq2{\*\panose 020B0604020202020204}Arial;}
{\f1\fswiss\fcharset161\fprq2 Arial Greek;}
{\f2\froman\fcharset2\fprq2{\*\panose 05050102010706020507}Symbol;}}
{\colortbl;\red0\green0\blue0;}
{\stylesheet{\s0\ltrpar\itap0\nowidctlpar\ql\li0\ri0\lin0\rin0\cbpat0\rtlch\af1\afs24\ltrch\f1\fs24 [Normal];}{\*\cs10\additive Default Paragraph Font;}}
{\info
{\*\txInfo{\txVer 24.0.712.500}}}
\paperw12240\paperh15840\margl1138\margt1138\margr1138\margb1138\deftab1134\widowctrl\lytexcttp\formshade\sectd
\headery567\footery567\pgwsxn12240\pghsxn15840\marglsxn1138\margtsxn1138\margrsxn1138\margbsxn1138\pgbrdropt32\pard\ltrpar\itap0\nowidctlpar\ql\li0\ri0\lin0\rin0\plain\rtlch\af0\afs20\alang1033\ltrch\f0\fs20\lang1033\langnp1033\langfe1033\langfenp1033 Hello, \par\par This is an example!\par\par
{\shp{\*\shpinst\shpleft0\shptop0\shpright7500\shpbottom3450\shpfhdr0\shpbxcolumn\shpbxignore\shpbypara\shpbyignore\shpwr2\shpwrk0\shpz0\shplid1025{\sp{\sn shapeType}{\sv 75}}{\sp{\sn fFlipH}{\sv 0}}{\sp{\sn fFlipV}{\sv 0}}{\sp{\sn wzName}{\sv _tx_id_1_}}{\sp{\sn pib}{\sv {\pict\jpegblip\picw13229\pich6085\picwgoal7500\pichgoal3450\picscalex100\picscaley100 
ffd8ffe000104a46494600010101006000600000ffe101024578696600004d4d002a000000080007011a0005000000010000
0062011b0005000000010000006a012800030000000100020000013100020000001100000072013b00020000000700000084
ff0011dbd85aebb65a6ead089ededb55b7d2f51d5b4f8af6253b654b4d4af61071b6e24fbc403d62800a002800a002800a00
2800a002800a002800a002800a002800a002800a002800a002800a002800a002800a002800a002800a002800a002800a0028
00a002800a002800a002800a002800a002800a002803ffd9}}}\par }
```

In the above example I paste a small fragment of the image, as the image representation was too large to fit here.

Comment: Would you be able to provide some sample RTF so I can see the kind of structure you are dealing with?

Comment: @JonIles I paste an example, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added some sample code for you to the RTF Parser Kit repository in the form of an `ImageListener` class which you'll find [here](https://github.com/joniles/rtfparserkit/blob/master/src/main/java/com/rtfparserkit/utils/ImageListener.java) and a simple "driver" class which shows how it is used [here](https://github.com/joniles/rtfparserkit/blob/master/src/main/java/com/rtfparserkit/utils/ImageDump.java).

The code takes a naive approach, simply looking for the `pict` command, expecting it to be the first command in a group, then adding any further commands in the group and their parameters to a `Map` (including the image data as a string of hex data). Once it gets to the end of the group it'll call a method you provide, passing the populated `Map`.

Unfortunately this is where the hard work starts as you'll need to interpret the keys in the `Map` to determine what the image type is and based on that, how to convert the hex data into an image you can work with.